# Why does my visual studio closes automatically without any errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crash, crash-reports

it is the latest version of visual studio  pro 2019
and there is new folder on my desktop named .vs
[image]

and the desktop folder contains a folder named v16 and it contains a file named .suo
[image]

Can it be because of the "CloneSpy" that i installed before today before using visual studio?
And what should i do?

Comment: The `.vs` folder is created at the root level of any *VS* `*.csproj` and `*.sln`. Did you save anything in the desktop folder ?

Comment: i didnt even use the visual studio today and it was made by itself 
2 files and 1 folder 
first file : slnx.sqlite
second file :VSWorkspaceState.json
and the folder is named Desktop
the folder contains another folder named "v16" and there is a file in v16 named : .suo which is :Visual Studio Solution User Options (.suo)

Comment: You can delete the .vs folder without problem because it contains temporary files and user cache and some others things like with a net browser. If it was recreated, you have a problem with something related with VS... Close VS, delete it, start VS and see what's happen... It is the same with the .suo and .user files. Perhaps you can check if the default saving path for new projects is not the desktop itself.

Comment: You can try to uninstall and reinstall VS. Or use a MS cleanup tool...

Comment: i deleted the .vs folder and the problem is not solved
when i open VS to create or open a project , it closes automatically without any error or sth.
so your suggestion is that i should uninstall VS and install it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the `.vs` folder without problem because it contains temporary files, user cache data and some others things like with a net browser. It is the same with .suo and .user files.

You can try to uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio as well as use the Cleanup Tool :

https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio

learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio.

You also should delete all registry keys like :

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio`

And drive folders like :

`c:\Program Files [& x86]\Microsoft Visual Studio [...]`

`c:\ProgramData\Microsoft Visual Studio\`

`c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio`

`c:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio`

`c:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio Services\`

`c:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSApplicationInsights\`

`c:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon\`

`c:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio`

After that, you may want to run a registry cleaner like CCleaner or Yamicsoft Windows Manager.

If it does not work... the last action is to reinstall Windos itself if you don't find anything to solve that. Before doing that you can try Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: will the folders be deleted automatically after i uninstall the visual studio ?
and how can i backup my settings ?

Comment: No. If VS crash at startup even without a project, you should delete all these things after uninstalled and launched the cleanup tool to do a total cleanup and avoid spurious data. If it is a project that close VS, when opening a form for example, perhaps there is some code like Application.Exit in some components/controls that is executed at design time...

Comment: Hi again ... i did everything u told me :I uninstalled the visual studio and then I deleted all those folders and after that I was going to use Cleanup tool and at there it was told to run cmd and paste a command.after I did that the cmd told me the file was not found and the website it was told that if u face this error u should install visual studio and after u should do that cmd command.I did all that and now when Im trying to install visual studio for the last time, it's telling that Visual studio can't be installed in a nonempty folder.

Comment: I checked the installation location and it was true.there was something there.so I deleted all of them and I wanna know that can that "deleting the things in installation location" make me some problems in future?

Comment: U know that's kinda strange to ask ... but did u understand what I just told u? Because I'm not European or native-English speaker and Im not sure If understood what I just was telling u ...  so did u get what I meant to ask?

Comment: It's annoying. I told you to run the VS cleanup tool before deleting regkeys & directories. Are you sure you deleted all registry keys, and all folders. You must be able to install VS again... else there is a problem. Search on drive all "visual studio" folders & delete them. Search in the registry all "visual studio" and delete them. You can use Total Commander and RegEditX, for example. In last hope, you will need to reinstall Windows, or restore your partition (using Macrium Reflect or O&O DiskImage for example) when VS works last (backup your current part before to restore your user data).

Comment: Deleting VS program folders and mentionned registry keys cause no problem. You missed something so VS install tell you the error message.

Comment: Don't delete your user data and projects, of course...

Comment: Last question.I promise. I don't actually know how to delete registery keys Or understand if have deleted them or not.Can u explain it abit or I would look it up on the Internet?

Comment: Run from the command line or the windows runbox "regedit". Navigate to keys mentionned and delete them. If you did not do that, it can explain why the installer refused to run after deleted folders... (I added the localmachine I've forgotten)

Answer (score 7):

For Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition

Renaming the folder

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon\OnlineLicensing\VisualStudio

Worked for me.

Comment: This also worked for me, thanks Muhammad,, but just wanted to add that if you have more than 1 version of Visual Studio you can remove the folder for the version under: "C:\Users\xxUSER-NAMExxx\AppData\Local\microsoft\VSCommon\OnlineLicensing\VisualStudio\xxxxxx".... (optionally backup if desired, but these folders will get recreated)

Answer (score 0):

It maybe caused by installing .net framework 4.7 and below after visual studio installation
if so, check the following solution:

1. edit machine.config for .net framework v4 (usually on this path: *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config*
   and this one :
   *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config*
   )
2. make sure the following config is set to false :

   ```
   <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="false" />
   ```

It works for me