# My Visual Studio is completely broken and I can't fix it. No errors just doesn't run

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Alright so I'm just starting to learn C#, I'm not the most savy with everything yet, I'm trying to learn but this issue has really hindered me from going forward learning C#. So basically no matter what I do I can't run a project. Even though there are no errors it will pop up that the build failed. And this happens across ALL my projects even any new one I create. Currently the only way for me to get it to run is by going into developer command prompt and doing dotnet build. This will let it run UNTIL I change even 1 detail about the code and then it stops working. I have uninstalled Visual Studio Community and reinstalled, that didn't work. I uninstalled again as well as deleting all the SDK's and programs with it in control panel, as well as going and deleting all the files related to visual studio in my file explorer and regedit, that didn't work. I even did a Windows reset to try to fix the issue, that also didn't work. Btw I get no error messages it just says build failed even if I change verbosity to detailed or diagnostic. I have tried discord groups but no one has been able to help me. The only lead I think I might have is that my Package Manager Console says

> "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
> type 'EnvDTE80.DTE2'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface
> call on the COM component for the interface with IID
> '{2EE1E9FA-0AFE-4348-A89F-ED9CB45C99CF}' failed due to the following
> error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).".

To help you guys try and figure out the problem I went and got logs so hopefully this help. I went and looked through the logs myself and there are a couple of errors and warnings mostly pertaining to Nuget Package Manager. I'm sorry about how messy the logs look I don't know how to share them the same way I can see them. Just look for where it says error. [Logs](https://www.codepile.net/pile/apgnv2lg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try starting VS with the [/SafeMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) parameter (ie `devenv.exe /SafeMode`). Have you tried *repairing* Visual Studio from the installer?

Comment: Yes I have tried repairing. I will try safemode now

Comment: I entered safemode but I don't really see what I'm supposed to do in safemode. I can't run my projects they don't even pop up.

Comment: It shows that your build is failing. What do you see in the "Build" section of the "Output" panel? Is there anything in your "Error List" panel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my visual studio closes automatically without any errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703847/why-does-my-visual-studio-closes-automatically-without-any-errors)

Answer (score -1):

I read through your question and the first thing I would suggest you do since you have gone through multiple uninstalls would be to ensure you are opening Visual Studio as the ADMIN profile.

Right Click on the Visual Studio from your Start Menu
Go to MORE
RUN AS Administrator

The reason being, Visual Studio might not have the correct permissions to access some required system files and that MAY be the issue you are running into.

After this, my second suggestion would be to clear out all TEMPs WHERE Logs are stored as well...

[How do you clear your Visual Studio cache on Windows Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520593/how-do-you-clear-your-visual-studio-cache-on-windows-vista)

While you are deleting System Registries, there might still be fragments stopping the system from completely starting on a clean slate.

Finally, ensure you are installing the X32 bit of Visual Studio Community

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: `ensure you are installing the X64 bit of Visual Studio Community` why? VS 2019 worked just fine as a 32-bit application all these years.

Comment: There is no 64 bit version of Visual Studio Community

Comment: There is no 64-bit version of VS2019 in any SKU. 64-bit is coming in VS2022: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022/