# Can't Install or Uninstall Visual Studio 2017/2019

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I have previously installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 but I forgot to add the .NET component for programming in unity. When I tried to launch the Visual Studio Installer, it shows me this:

[It gives me this specific error code when running the installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ews7N.jpg)

Then, when I tried to download the latest version of Visual Studio 2019, it gives me two errors when running the installer:

[Failed to download Channel. Unable to download the channel from link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDRcV.jpg)

[A product matching the following parameters could not be found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVRsj.jpg)

Also, for some reason, uninstalling it doesn't seem to work as when I tried to uninstall it via the add/remove programs on Windows 10, it says it's completing the uninstall but when I restart it's still there.

Lastly, I've tried to use the VisualStudioUninstaller tool on GitHub but even then when using it, it still results in the same errors. I also checked my Visual Studio folders but there is no InstallCleanup.exe no matter how many times I try to run the installer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703847/why-does-my-visual-studio-closes-automatically-without-any-errors/62713351#62713351

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my visual studio closes automatically without any errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703847/why-does-my-visual-studio-closes-automatically-without-any-errors)

Answer (score 0):

The error you report is usually related to a corrupt or out sync `.vs` cache. Usually, deleting the hidden folder in the root of your solution does solve the issue. If furthermore, manually cleaning the file system by deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders for each project might help sometimes.

For additional troubleshooting, please have a look to [Why does my visual studio closes automatically without any errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703847/why-does-my-visual-studio-closes-automatically-without-any-errors/62713351#62713351)

Answer (score -1):

faced same type of problem,  during that i resolved  by deleting registry files then rebooted my machine.