# How can I open design editor for forms in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This might be a really stupid question, but I am new to C# and I wanted to create a simple form. I can't open it into the Designer, only the code is displayed. Even if i click "View Designer" (Shift + F7), nothing is happening.

Maybe someone can help me. Thank you!
[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Have you tried on Form1.cs, not Form1.Designer.cs? 99% of the time, you don't need to pay any attention to *Designer.cs files.

Comment: Double click `Form1.cs`.

Comment: when I click on Form1, it just opens the form in code version, but not in design

Comment: Create a new project: does it do the same? Thus try [Repair/Reinstall/Clean Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703847/why-does-my-visual-studio-closes-automatically-without-any-errors/62713351#62713351)

Comment: Likely what @OlivierRogier mentioned. You could also be missing some setting when you installed VS. Confirm in the VS Installer that you have selected the Windows Desktop workload

Comment: @allesmoegliche, If you still have the problem after you reinstall/repair visual studio install the correct workload, I recommend that you could report an issue in [Develop Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home).

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem: I used net Core (has no Designer) and switched then to net Framework (with Designer)