# Suggestion of Visual stuido 2019, background is transparency

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

Sometimes, Visual studio's suggestion's background is transparency, it makes me hard to read

I attach some picture.

Anyone have a idea to solve this problem?

[image: please click this to see picture]

Comment: Try to change colors or theme, or to reset settings, otherwise to [repair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703847/why-does-my-visual-studio-closes-automatically-without-any-errors/62713351#62713351)

Comment: I did two things(change color and theme, to reset setting), repair is last option, anyway thanks

Comment: Also, consider if this issue is caused by an installed extension. Try to disable any of them and see if this works.

Comment: So, is your issue fixed and everything works fine now?