# How to enable code suggestions in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

I have been working with IntellIJ before. There I get suggestions on which function of my library I might want to use when typing. I noticed that in Microsoft Visual Studio this is not the case. Can I enable it somewhere?

[image: IntellIJ IDE]

*update *

I am getting suggestions about local variables and functions, but not functions and classes of the Unity library I use:

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand the question but maybe you can find what you want with things like https://oz-code.com or https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper

Comment: @OlivierRogier I want Microsoft Visual Studio to do the same as IntellIJ does in the screenshot: giving me suggestions about other functions/variables in my code or in libraries that I use

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what means "*giving me suggestions about other functions/variables in my code or in libraries that I use*" because it is intellisense itself. Do you mean it does not worh with your Visual Studio? Thus try reset settings or [repair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703847/why-does-my-visual-studio-closes-automatically-without-any-errors/62713351#62713351). But I definitively don't understand what means "*indexing*" ... and I don't know IntellJ.

Comment: @OlivierRogier yes it does not work, errors in code are not marked by the IDE either

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you see in Visual Studio? IntelliSense is enabled by default for solutions and cannot (easily?) be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Unity, open Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools -> External Script Editor and from the drop down list select  Visual Studio XXX (2017,.. etc).

If this is not in the drop down, select "Browse..." from drop down, go into Visual Studio installation path, by default in Windows OS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\XXX(2017, 2019,....)\Enterprise\Common7\IDE" and select "devenv.exe" file.

Now in the drop down, Visual Studio will have appeared. Close the Preferences window and open the project from "Assets -> Open C# Project". and please check the using too, I hope it helps to solve the problem!

Answer (score -1):

So I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but you can only get suggestions for classes in Visual Studio if you specify the associated namespace, in your case the Unity library, e.g. using UnityLibary .....

Comment: I have done that. `using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;`

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.