# Visual Studio 2022 Community crashes on startup due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When I try to open Visual Studio Community 2022, it starts to open the project and then crashes during startup. I found two error entries in the Windows Event Viewer, one with a source of ".NET Runtime:"

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 00007FF8E9CC60D2 (00007FF8E9B70000) with exit code 80131506.
```

and one with a source of "Application Error":

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 17.3.32819.101, time stamp: 0x62ffc31b
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.8.4515.0, time stamp: 0x624ce98e
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000001560d2
Faulting process id: 0x2cb8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8ba3947f2203d
Faulting application path: E:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: cd8112a8-9515-4b46-89de-1d714c244e5c
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Exception code 0xc0000005 is apparently an access violation.

I haven't been able to find much information about this as it applies specifically to Visual Studio. I found [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-0xc0000005-error-when-you-open-a-visual-studio-solution-in-a-localized-version-of-visual-studio-2010-sp1-ac02a5b4-752f-d121-26d3-e971048e7891) from Microsoft, but it's unfortunately about Visual Studio 2010 (which is ancient history by now).

According to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703847/why-does-my-visual-studio-closes-automatically-without-any-errors), installing a version of the .NET Framework prior to 4.7 after Visual Studio is installed. Windows Update did recently install some updates to that, so this *might* be the source of the problem (but I'm not sure). Unfortunately, the answer that mentions this isn't too specific about what to do to fix this or why this would cause problems, other than you needing to make some unspecified changes to a machines.config file. Also, I tried repairing Visual Studio, and even uninstalling and reinstalling it, and it didn't help at all.

Can someone explain why this would be a problem, and what I can do to fix this?

Comment: That kind of crash indicates either bad hardware (disk) or corrupt .NET Framework installation. As .NET Framework is part of Windows today, you might have to reinstall Windows and see if that brings things back to normal.

Comment: I can only go by the "Access Violation" error code, but [earlier this year I had this problem and could solve it by removing cached licensing information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76092834/1843468). Access denied and access violation shouldn't be the same (one is virtual access rights and one is memory access), but maybe that helps you, too?