# Cannot open Visual Studio 2022 (UnauthorizedAccessException in LoadPackageWithContext)

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2022

As of today, when I try to open Visual Studio 2022, it briefly opens the welcome window (where you select the solution from the pinned or recently opened items), then freezes in that white-out state before closing immediately.

I've already tried updating from version 17.3.5 to 17.5.4 (which is the latest version to date), as well as restarting my PC, but to no avail.

I have tried to trouble-shoot the problem by [starting Visual Studio in safe mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022) using the command line:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\"
devenv /SafeMode /Log "%USERPROFILE%\VSSafeModeLog.xml"
```

This gave the following message:

```
An exception was encountered while constructing the content of this frame.
This information is also logged in "C:\Users\MyUserName\VSSafeModeLog.xml".

Exception details:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied (Exception by HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShell5.LoadPackageWithContext(Guid& packageGuid, Int32 reason, Guid& context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.GetPackage()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.<ConstructContent>g__ConstructContentFromPackage|145_1(WindowFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()
```

I looked into the `VSSafeModeLog.xml` (which appears to be just the re-routed `ActivityLog.xml` from `AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio`), and found this close to the end (entries below were only of type "Information"):

```
<entry>
  <record>920</record>
  <time>2023/04/24 09:58:34.413</time>
  <type>Warning</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>License validation task failed unexpectedly. The application will be shutdown.</description>
</entry>
```

And a bit further up I found this entry:

```
<entry>
  <record>914</record>
  <time>2023/04/24 09:58:34.064</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>VS/LicensingNotifications/InitializeNotifications</source>
  <description>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceUnavailableException: The SVsToastService service is unavailable.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.LicensingNotifications.LicensingNotificationsProvider.&lt;InitializeNotificationsAsync&gt;d__20.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.LicensingNotifications.LicensingNotificationsProvider.&lt;&lt;InitializeNotifications&gt;b__19_0&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskLibraryHelper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass35_0.&lt;&lt;FileAndForget&gt;b__0&gt;d.MoveNext()</description>
</entry>
```

Here is the unescaped stack trace information from the description tag:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceUnavailableException: The SVsToastService service is unavailable.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.LicensingNotifications.LicensingNotificationsProvider.<InitializeNotificationsAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.LicensingNotifications.LicensingNotificationsProvider.<<InitializeNotifications>b__19_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskLibraryHelper.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<<FileAndForget>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

I don't recognize that service by its name, I do not have any service or even a file on my system with that name. But neither do my co-workers, and their VS 2022 installations are working fine.

We are all using Visual Studio 2022 Professional with online licensing in Microsoft 365. I'm not having trouble using/signing in with other 365 services, like OneDrive for example.

I have been Googling for a while and found many topics for the various error messages, depending on what bits of error messages, error codes or stack traces I am searching for. Most of the solutions seem to be very "broad", such as updating VS (which I already tried), re-installing VS (which didn't seem to help them, so I'd like to keep that option for last), or using `sfc /scannow` (which I think is actually just the modern version of the "Defrag your hard drive" classic).

There are some quite promising threads from Microsoft Q&A and Developer Community, which even include the "licensing" bit or a familiar part of a stack trace. But all of them only got one reply from a Microsoft employee asking for more detail that went unanswered at thus these threads were closed, or the problem was still unresolved when the thread fell silent, or it was marked as "resolved by VS update", which obviously doesn't apply for my case:

- [Visual Studio 2019 constantly crashing - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/416743/visual-studio-2019-constantly-crashing)
- [Construction of frame content failed. - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/402278/construction-of-frame-content-failed)
- [Visual Studio 2019 - unable to open solution under git source control - Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-2019-unable-to-open-solution-under-g/1478644)
- [VS 2017 15.3 crashes opening any new or existing project - Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-2017-153-crashes-opening-any-new-or-existing-pr/94904)
- [Visual Studio crashes on solution load - Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-crashes-on-solution-load/94099) (from the link above)

Anything else I can try before resetting my whole ecosystem of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled "Visual Studio licensing crash" and found [Visual Studio 2022 crashing on startup - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1116991/visual-studio-2022-crashing-on-startup), which has a different context according to the stack traces, but it suggest that the directory `\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon\OnlineLicensing\VisualStudio` contains the online licensing information and might get corrupted, causing this kind of error and subsequent crash.

Close Visual Studio, and inside that directory, find the folder called `17.0` (which is the version number of "Visual Studio 2022"). Rename it into `_17.0`, and then try to start Visual Studio again. Visual Studio should create a new `17.0` folder and continue to start normally.

The linked thread suggests the contents of the folder can become corrupted, but it is redundant/just a cache for licensing information, that can be easily rebuilt when the folder goes "missing" due to the renaming.